# Necessary when changing the image, free memory from the previous image

Tags: c#, wpf

Below is the code in which the garbage collector removes only every third loaded image, the last two images are resident in memory. It is very critical for large images and periodically leads to "OutOfMemoryException"

```
private void map()
        {            
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();            
            byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer); 
            BitmapImage bitmap33 = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap33.BeginInit();           
            bitmap33.StreamSource = ms;
            bitmap33.EndInit();
            bitmap33.Freeze();
            img.Source = bitmap33;  
        }
```

Comment: Did you make sure that there are no references to it?

Comment: without deeper understanding i would guess that some of the code might only map to com object wrappers, which open a seperate thread and therefore don´t get garbage-collected. probably proper use of dispose might solve ur issues.

Comment: First thing to do to make the GC do what you want, is leave it alone. I doubt that collect call is doing anything but promoting the generation and what is img, and I see no attempt to free anything here, or even manage it's lifetime.

Comment: Please run your application through [Perfview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/09/improving-your-app-s-performance-with-perfview.aspx) before making assumptions about what is using your memory. You might be right, but having empirical evidence will speed things up massively.

Comment: Why not use the constructor that [takes a URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass in the path to the image as a URI?

Comment: I can not PerfView find the information I needed. In VMMap clearly shows that memory in the heap. I suspect that's to blame Bitmapimage, but I can not do anything with it. From Uri I left after the problem, and as a possible variant of its solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tools like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and [PerfView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/09/improving-your-app-s-performance-with-perfview.aspx) to see if your process keeps a file handle on the specific files and determine the exact current behavior of your code.

I would suggest using the `using` keyword. As the [MSDN using statement reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) says, "files are examples of managed types that access unmanaged resources ... The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way".

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. But I could not solve the problem. Use "using" in his situation, I could not (perhaps due to lack of experience) as well as specific and PerfView in my case. I will be glad to any practical example of solving such problems =)

Comment: Do you see any open handles in the Process Explorer? Have you defined when the handles are left open and when they are not? Does anything different happen when the files are left open (not closing a `Stream` or something? When you close the application, do the handles free?